# Insert into table without all values

Tags: python, sqlite

Specifically, how would I insert into sqlite3 database and python without using all the values.

If my table is setup like this:

```
People:    
f_name | l_name | age | favorite_color
```

When I create a new row, how would I be able to only put in a few values like this:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO People VALUES (?, ?)", (f_name, l_name))
```

Right now it would give an error for only filling two of the four columns.

Comment: Literally the first google result for SQL INSERT syntax explains it.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to list the columns explicitly:

`c.execute("INSERT INTO People (f_name, l_name) VALUES (?, ?)", (f_name, l_name))`

Answer (score 0):

1) INSERT statement doesn't automatically know what value goes where if you omit some parameters. It is generally good practice to explicitly mentioning the names of the columns. e.g: INSERT INTO People (f_name, l_name)

2) If those columns aren't nullable then you can't omit them at all!